# SSIS import xls file and split it in 2, after the empty row

Tags: ssis, null, split, xls

I have an excel file with bunch of data separated by 2 empty rows. I need to separate this 2 data sets into two CSV files. So in SSIS Data Flow I picked "Excel Source" next "Conditional Split" and "Flat file destination". Question is how to setup split to do the job?

Excel data example:

Server_name | PrimarySA | SecondarySA 
srv1        | SA1       | SA1
srv2        | SA2       | SA2
 
srv3        | SA3       | SA3
empty row            |           |
empty row             |           |
srvA        | SAa       | SAa
srvB        | SAb       | SAb
srvC        | SAc       | SAc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution 1:

1.1 Create a stage table :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Stage]
(
    [RowID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Server_name ] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [PrimarySA ] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [SecondarySA ] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

2.2 DFT1 - Load the data. Source: XL file, Destination: Stage table

2.3 DFT2 - Source

```
SELECT [RowID]
      ,[Server_name ]
      ,[ PrimarySA ]
      ,[ SecondarySA ]
FROM [dbo].[Stage]
WHERE 
    RowID < (SELECT MIN (RowID) 
             FROM [dbo].[Stage] where [Server_name ] = 'empty row '
             )

Destination: A new flat file File1
```

2.4 DFT 3:
Source:

```
 SELECT [RowID]
      ,[Server_name ]
      ,[ PrimarySA ]
      ,[ SecondarySA ]
 FROM [dbo].[Stage]
 WHERE RowID > (SELECT MAX (RowID) from [dbo].[Stage] where [Server_name ] = 'empty row ')

Destination: Another flat file - File2
```

Solution 2: Do it in a script task. Read each line, check the length or the content of the line.  If a blank line is not found, write to File 1. If blank line found, close the first file, open a new output file and write to this one.

This will require more programming knowledge, but would be able to handle a file with multiple "empty lines". If you need this solution (and get stuck), please let us know; I or someone else will help you.

Comment: Thanks for advise. I am developing small script tasks as you mentioned in solution 2. I will share the code any time soon.

Comment: Sure. I will be glad to help you.